# Linking a collection to another file

Tags: linked-data, collections

I'm in the process of creating a complex mechanical system and i would like to separate the various sub-systems in separate files having one "main" file with each sub-system linked to it. I'm trying to do it with collections (having the objects I need linked from each file in one collection and linking that collection). I can successfully link the collections to my main file. My problem is that each linked collection contains other collections (with "cutter" objects for booleans for example) which I don't want to be rendered and I have disabled the rendering option but when linked the property doesn't "transfer".

[image: Here (the file is to be linked) I have the "Cutters" collection disabled for rendering]

Here (the file is to be linked) I have the "Cutters" collection disabled for rendering

[[image: Here (in the main file) the "linked" Cutters collection is not disabled for rendering2]

Here (in the main file) the "linked" Cutters collection is not disabled for rendering

Is there any way to link the collection with all its properties?

Comment: Workaround: Keep you file structure as is, but add a new collection specifically for linking that only has the desired objects linked to, and no child collections

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm doing it this way so I am able to make changes as this is not necessarily the final version of the "Legs" collection and I'm trying to keep things tidy